# How to use repository in factory

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository, factory

Hi
I'm trying to make application in accordance with the DDD. I'm have the following entities:

```
public class Item 
{
       public Category Category { get; protected set; }

       ...
}

public class SpecificItem : Item
{
       ...
}

public class Category 
{
       public static int IdOfCategoryForSpecificItem = 10;

       public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And now I would like to create **factory** with method that create object of **SpecificItem** type. But this specific item must be in specific category. So I created factory like this:

```
public class ItemFactory
{
       public static SpecificItem CreateSpecificItem(object someArguments)
       {
            IRepository<Category> repository = null // How to get repository?

            return new SpecificItem
            {
                 Category = repository.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == Category.IdOfCategoryForSpecificItem),
                 // additional initialization
            };
       }
}
```

And now my questions:

1. It is correct way to create factory and use repository?
2. How to get repository? I can't use DI because it's static method. I don't like ServiceLocator because it's difficult to unit testing.
3. Maybe there are better solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rewrite your `ItemFactory` to use dependency injection and inject the `IRepository<Category>` using constructor injection. After doing that, the `ItemFactory` will look like this:

```
public class ItemFactory
{
    private readonly IRepository<Category> repository;

    public ItemFactory(IRepository<Category> repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public SpecificItem CreateSpecificItem(object someArguments)
    {
        return new SpecificItem
        {
             Category = this.repository.FirstOrDefault(i => 
                 i.Id == Category.IdOfCategoryForSpecificItem),
             // additional initialization
        };
    }
}
```

This way you moved the responsibility of retrieving an implementation of `IRepository<Category>` to the caller. Now you can do the same for all types that need the `ItemFactory`. Inject the `ItemFactory` as dependency in the constructors of these types. Do this all the way up to the top of your application's type hierarchy and compose the types their (the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx)).

Especially IoC/DI frameworks will get very handy to automate the creation of types for you.

Comment: The only concern that I have is that Category doesn't seem that it should have a repository at least in the DDD sense because it doesn't provide persistence services for an Aggregate Root. Using a repository at the ORM level here may make sense however since at least it is my understanding that a factory implementation is still considered application infrastructure.

Comment: Should `IRepository` be immutable? If not, then factory will produce different result for the same arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making **Dao** and **Service** classes. While Dao organizes access to data, Service uses Dao to manage data. The schema is:
1) Dao-class is getting access to data
2) Service-class is forming the repository
3) Service-class providing the repository for your factory
It's very generalized schema, but I hope my answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those times that puzzling over syntax is leading you toward a better solution.

It seems likely that you might want a different repository for each class, which is exactly what DI can do for you and which a static property would prevent.

But I also think you're confusing your names here - a factory creates NEW items of some type while a repopsitory stores/persists items of that type. Are you creating or retrieving?

My suggestion is to split these up - implement a factory to create new ones and an repository to save/retreive existing ones. Use DI to decide which concrete implementation based on type at run-time.